# plsql multiple case, regex matching

Tags: oracle, plsql

I wrote a search tool using Oracle Apex 5 which has 2 specific filter/search fields. I am attempting to search one or both, but I am not getting the desired result. Let's say I have Name Surname columns in my table and use Name Surname search field. The data will therefore look like this:

```
Name    | Surname
--------------------
Phil    | Anselmo
Max     | Cavalera
Maynard | Keenan
Kurt    | Cobain
David   | Gilmour
```

My Search fields in Apex will be:

```
:P1_NAME
:P1_SURNAME
```

I want match either of the following criteria:

```
regexp_like(NAME, :P1_NAME, 'i') and regexp_like(SURNAME, :P1_SURNAME, 'i')

or

:P1_NAME is null and regexp_like(SURNAME, :P1_SURNAME, 'i')

or

:P1_SURNAME is null and regexp_like(NAME, :P1_NAME, 'i')
```

But I am unsure of how to incorporate it into a single select? Here is my latest select. I tried quite a few others though.

```
select name, surname, from leads 
where :P1_SURNAME is null and regexp_like(NAME, :P1_NAME, 'i')
or :P1_NAME is null and regexp_like(SURNAME, :P1_SURNAME, 'i')
or regexp_like(NAME, :P1_NAME, 'i') and regexp_like(SURNAME, :P1_SURNAME, 'i')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select seems fine if you add braces for grouping conditions:

```
select name, surname, from leads 
    where (:P1_SURNAME is null and regexp_like(NAME, :P1_NAME, 'i'))
    or (:P1_NAME is null and regexp_like(SURNAME, :P1_SURNAME, 'i'))
    or (regexp_like(NAME, :P1_NAME, 'i') and regexp_like(SURNAME, :P1_SURNAME, 'i'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to put brackets around the conditions inside each or, i.e.:

```
select name, surname
from   leads 
where  (:P1_SURNAME is null and regexp_like(NAME, :P1_NAME, 'i'))
or     (:P1_NAME is null and regexp_like(SURNAME, :P1_SURNAME, 'i'))
or     (regexp_like(NAME, :P1_NAME, 'i') and regexp_like(SURNAME, :P1_SURNAME, 'i'))
```

That means at least one set of those conditions must be true, and within each condition, both sub-conditions must be true to make that condition true.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select name, surname from leads
where 
instr( upper(:P1_SURNAME), upper(SURNAME) ) + instr( upper(:P1_NAME), upper(NAME) ) > 0
```

Comment: Does not seem like my regex search will function any longer?

Comment: It will work. But `instr` solution looks more clearly and might run faster.